# INS-20802 Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.in oracle 19c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c, error-messaging

when i install oracle 19c when configuration of database this error appeared
when i open log file this line was there

```
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Gathering system details...
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Registering setup bean
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Building Flow
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Opening bean stores from which the beans can be loaded
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Loading beanstore from a given input stream
WARNING:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Unable to create xml tag for the key:CommonProgramFiles(x86)
WARNING:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Unable to create xml tag for the key:ProgramFiles(x86)
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Translating external format into raw format 
INFO:  [Oct 3, 2023 2:58:28 AM] Loaded BeanStore using the flow data defaults
```

i tried to remove oracle from windows and reinstall but the same error appeared